# Reading large Binary files fails in Rebol

Tags: http, rebol

The following Rebol code fails due to an `out of memory` error:

```
read/binary http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/lucid/
            ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso
```

How can I use Rebol to read large binary files over HTTP?

Comment: This question is a topic of conversation on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53547/dealing-with-moderators-who-close-a-question-due-to-ignorance-of-tagged-languag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebol 2 ports are something of a mess.  So you can't directly apply the sample of how to [read a large file in parts](http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Port_Examples#Read_all_of_large_file) because `read` doesn't work on `port!` in R2 (much less does `read/part` work).

But if you jump through some hoops and use the `/direct` refinement to directly open the file, you get something that will work:

```
; Rebol 2 chunking http download sample

filename: %ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso
base-url: http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/lucid/
chunk-size: 32000

in-port: open/binary/direct rejoin [base-url filename]
out-port: open/binary/direct filename
while [not none? data: copy/part in-port chunk-size] [
    append out-port data
]
close in-port
close out-port
```

*(**UPDATE:** I didn't notice the READ-IO sample [that Sunanda cites](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-13.html#section-11.12), as I don't use R2 much and hadn't ever seen READ-IO.  It may also work on http and have better performance.  But I'll let you do that comparison.  :P)*

In Rebol 3, you can read and write from a `port!`.  That means a modification of the large file sample *should* work, *in theory*...

```
; Rebol 3 chunking http download sample
; Warning: does not work in A99 release

filename: %ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso
base-url: http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/lucid/
chunk-size: 32000

in-port: open/read rejoin [base-url filename]
out-port: open/write filename
while [not empty? data: read/part in-port chunk-size] [
    write out-port data
]
close in-port
close out-port
```

Yet there's a bug in the current build of R3 alpha that ignores the `/part` refinement and goes ahead and returns the contents of the whole file during `read` if the scheme is HTTP.  :(

Answer (score 2):

Use this http://anton.wildit.net.au/rebol/util/batch-download.r to download large files.

Comment: Seems great but it's wrapped into a context with no name. So how am i supposed to use it ?

I tried to extract batch-download function but I got weird error about missing brackets.

Comment: You can expose it by removing the context, or, by creating another function that is global.  Eg. before the end of the context

`set 'bd :batch-download`

and then you can use the 'bd function.  Eg:

`bd/to-dir [ http://www.http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso ] %downloads/`

started downloading.  I aborted it at 10% as I don't want this file.

Answer (score 1):

A straight read of a large file may fail as it is held in memory and may exhaust the available memory.

This reference describes a way to read a file in chunks, provided you can find an FTP server to source it:
  http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-13.html#section-11.12

A quick search suggests there are FTP servers for Ubuntu, but I have not checked if they cover the version you need.  Good luck!